# Is it possible to extend class for limited types only?

Tags: crystal-lang

I would like to add `normalize` method to Arrays of Numbers only (Float & Int) as it doesn't make sense for String. But it won't compile, is that possible?

```
class Array(Number)
  def normalize
    multiplier = 1 / max
    map{ |v| multiplier * v }
  end
end

p [1, 2].normalize
```

Comment: No. But just extend if for all arrays, if a type doesn't support it it will still fail to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, as I'm sure you've seen. As such, you have two options.

1) You can extend the class into a new one that just uses the type you want.

```
class NumberArray < Array(Number)
  # Do something
end
```

The obvious downside being that you can't use an `Array(Number)` as a `NumberArray`.

2) You can write a guard clause around the `normalize` method that checks the array type and makes sure it's a number array.

```
class Array(T)
  def normalize
    {% unless T < Number %}
      {% raise "Expected Number type for Array#normalize, got #{T}" %}
    {% end %}
    multiplier = 1 / max
    map { |v| multiplier * v }
  end
end
```